# Parametric equation: $x=t^2, y=t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

Why there is a curve below x-axis? I thought that because square root is involved, y should be >= 0.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see a square root?  In $x=t^2,y=t$ there are no square root signs anywhere.  Consider, is $t$ allowed to be $-1$?  If $t$ *were* equal to $-1$ what does that imply that $x$ and $y$ should each be equal to?

Comment: Square root is not involved.

Comment: Well, this is how I understand it: $t=\sqrt x$ so $y=\sqrt x$. Am I wrong?

Comment: $t^2=x$ means $t=\pm\sqrt x$

Comment: Ahhhhh... thank you W. Tanner :) I always forget that :(

Comment: Why wouldn’t you instead interpret it as $y=t$ so $x=y^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$y=t$ can be negative. And $y<0$ is below $x$-axis. And $x=t^2 \ge 0$ so it lies
right of the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

This is because this is a little different than saying $y=x^2$. What we are basically doing is expressing the coordinates in terms of one parameter $t$. Here, we have that the coordinate $(x,y)$ is expressed as $(t^2, t)$. Hence, as $t^2 \geq 0$, the $x$ coordinate can never be less than zero, however, as the y coordinate $y=t$, we have that $y$ can be negative.

Example computations: let's walk along $t$ to see how this curve evolves.

for $t = 1$, we have $(x,y) = (1^2,1) = (1,1)$

for $t = 0$, we have $(x,y) = (0^2,0) = (0,0)$

for $t = -1$, we have $(x,y) = ((-1)^2,-1) = (1,-1)$

As you can see, we have a point lying beneath the $x$-axis